# Can cassandra create table over files stored in S3?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I know that Athena allows you to query data directly from files stored in Amazon S3 using SQL syntax. Athena doesn't have a storage system; instead, it creates a schema and metadata layer on top of the data stored in S3.

I know Hive also does something similar. With Hive, you can define external tables that reference data stored in S3, allowing you to query that data using HiveQL, which is similar to SQL.

Can we do something like this in Cassandra?
I want to have my files in S3 and query them using CQL in Cassandra.

Cassandra has a partition key and a clustering key.
The file name could be the partition key value and the clustering key should be data inside the file in sorted order.

Is there a way we can achieve such a solution?